# Integration of the function with good substitution

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\ln(x)}{1+\ln(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$ I surely know the integral would be of $u/v$ type but I am not getting any good substitution to go for it. I think $\log(x)=e^t$ would be good as we get again an $e^{e^t}$ so everything now is in $e$ but I can't go further with it. Thanks!

Comment: Your integral can not be expressed in elementary functions. It requires the use of the exponential integral. Check with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(x)%2F(1%2Blog(x)%5E2)).

Comment: It can be done if by log(x) you mean ln(x)

Comment: @bulbasaur Most people usually use $\log x$ as $\ln x$, at least on this site.

Comment: Ya I'll edit it sorry for confusion

Comment: By setting $x=e^{-t}$ you may check that an exponential integral is involved, namely $$\int \left(\frac{1}{t+i}+\frac{1}{t-i}\right) e^{-t}\,dt,$$ that is not an elementary integral.

Comment: Okay so can you please tell me how to go for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $u=\ln x$ and decompose
$$\int\frac{\ln x}{\ln ^2x+1}\,\mathrm d x=\int\frac{ue^u}{u^2+1}\,\mathrm d u=\frac 12\int\frac{e^u}{u+i}\,\mathrm d u+\frac 12\int\frac{e^u}{u-i}\,\mathrm du$$

These two integrals are [exponential integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), as it can be seen if you substitute for the denominators:
$$\frac 12\int\frac{e^u}{u+i}\,\mathrm d u+\frac 12\int\frac{e^u}{u-i}\,\mathrm du=\frac{e^{-i}}{2}\int\frac{e^v}{v}\,\mathrm d v+\frac{e^i}{2}\int\frac{e^t}{t}\,\mathrm d t=\frac{e^{-i}\operatorname{Ei}(v)}{2}+\frac{e^i\operatorname{Ei}(t)}{2}$$

Hence, the result is:
$$\int\frac{\ln x}{\ln ^2x+1}\,\mathrm d x=\frac{e^{-i}\operatorname{Ei}(\ln x+i)}{2}+\frac{e^i\operatorname{Ei}(\ln x-i)}{2}+C$$